# Commonalities in Hong Kong place names

Tags: cantonese, names, place-names, hong-kong

I've been in Hong Kong long enough to notice some patterns appearing in the names of Hong Kong's places. Most of the places had 角 or 灣 in them.

For example:
角: 旺角, 大角嘴, 北角, 沙頭角

灣: 灣仔, 西灣河,  銅鑼灣, 荃灣

Is there a reason why 'corner' and 'bay' are used very commonly for place names in Hong Kong? I can guess for 'bay' because Hong Kong is a harbor with coasts, quarries and bays.

But for 角, why would so many places be named after corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a page entitled [Place names of Hong Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_names_of_Hong_Kong), which mentions:

> - Kok (角) - point (of land), horn, angle

Point is also a common term in English place names.

---

A good example of this can be found on another Wiki page: [Origins of names of cities and towns in Hong Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_names_of_cities_and_towns_in_Hong_Kong). Here they have the example of 沙頭角:

> **City** | **Language Origins** |  **Meaning**
>
> Sha Tau Kok    | Chinese   | sandy head point

---

Another good example might be [North Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Point) (北角). As this [ejinsight](http://www.ejinsight.com/20150130-north-point-hong-kongs-living-history/) article examplains:

> Many of Hong Kong’s geographical place names have been in use for more than 150 years. Some describe their specific locations. North Point is one of them.
>
> North Point sits on the northernmost tip of Hong Kong Island, a major cross-harbor interchange on the MTR line.

Comment: Thanks! I actually know about that Wikipedia article but it is not comprehensive enough. It would be interesting to know why 角 is common.

Comment: @udidosa The same reason bay is so common, HK is on the water, there are bound to be many headlands.

Comment: You might also want to check those olds maps drawn before land reclamations.